# Replace NA's and delete columns in an efficient way

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which looks like follows:

```
# Code:
m3 <- c(NA, -3, NA, NA, -3)
m2 <- c(rep(NA, 5))
m1 <- c(rep(NA, 5))
Zero <- c(rep(NA, 5))
p1 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA)
p2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA)
p3 <- c(3, NA, 3, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(m3, m2, m1, Zero, p1, p2, p3)

# Output:
  m3 m2 m1 Zero p1 p2 p3
1 NA NA NA   NA  1 NA  3
2 -3 NA NA   NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA   NA NA NA  3
4 NA NA NA   NA  1  2  3
5 -3 NA NA   NA NA NA NA
```

I need to insert a -3 in the whole row, if there is a -3 in the first column. I also need to delete all columns, but p1, p2, and p3. The final result should look like follows:

```
# Final output:
  p1 p2 p3
1  1 NA  3
2 -3 -3 -3
3 NA NA  3
4  1  2  3
5 -3 -3 -3
```

I found a solution, but it seems very inefficient to me. I need to perform this operation multiple times and therefore need a code, which is as efficient as possible. My inefficient solution looks like follows:

```
# Inefficient code:
for(i in 1:length(df$m3)){
  if(is.na(df$m3[i]) == FALSE){
    df[i, ] <- -3
  }
}
df <- df[ , 5:length(df)]
```

Is there a more efficient way? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here is a `dplyr` version i.e. `library(dplyr);df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(m3==-3), -3)), starts_with('p')) %>%select(p1:p3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update values:

```
df[df$m3 %in% -3,] <- -3
```

select columns:

```
df <- df[, c("p1", "p2", "p3")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use data.table

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[m3 == -3, paste0('p', 1:3) := -3]
dt <- dt[, c("p1", "p2", "p3"), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: This could be achieved in a single line `setDT(df)[m3==-3, names(df)[5:7] := -3][, 1:4 := NULL]` or you can use `paste0('p', 1:3) := `

Comment: Thanks, just modified!

Comment: Deletion of columns by reference can be done with `:=NULL`, while `<-` copying may be a little inefficient. Not sure if you missed that part of akrun's comment.